# Пауза на видео если оно вышло за область видимости

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как понять, находится ли элемент (тег video) в области видимости или нет. Если нет, то ставить video на паузу (**`.pause()`**). Если такая тема была, дайте ссылочку, пожалуйста..не могу найти. Тегов (video) может быть 2..3..4 и т.д.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163756/html5-and-javascript-to-play-videos-only-when-visible/21164477

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: спасибо большое !